# Why &>> in system() call has different behavior between 3.3 and 3.4

Tags: r, shell

Run the following R code

```
system("sleep 10 &>> test.log")
```

under R 3.3.3, it correctly sleeps 10 secs, but under R 3.4.1, it exits immediately, looks like `sleep 10 & >> test.log`.

Is it a bug, since I don't find anything changed made to `system()` from R 3.3 to 3.4 at https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html?

The problem is resolved at ["&>>" in sh behaves differently in Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Fedora 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320065/in-sh-behaves-differently-in-ubuntu-16-04-2-and-fedora-24)

Comment: Hm.  Shouldn't it return immediately if you send the `sleep` into the background via `&`?

Comment: `sleep 10 &` should mean send to background, but `&>>` should mean direct stdout and stderr to file, at least they work in terminal and in previous R versions, but in R 3.4 exactly the same command behaves differently, and inconsistent with that in terminal.

Comment: Well, maybe take it to r-devel then?

Comment: yes, think this is a bug which caused weired problems here, like a binary writing to file and "exit" successfully but file.exists cannot find that file...

Comment: I saw https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/ is not open for registration, should I directly send an e-mail to R Core Team <R-core@r-project.org>?

Comment: As I said, I would send an email to r-devel. I am not sure if this is a bug in R.  Maybe your outer program should control when logging is done; the `sleep` seems a wee bit ad-hoc.  Or use a lockfile or mutex or ...

Comment: my actual usage is `system("some_binary output.csv &>> some.log")`, `some_binary` will write a nearly 100M data to `output.csv` and then it will be checked. In R 3.4, the behavior changes like `system()` returns 0 fast, then file checker cannot find `output.csv`, then some seconds later, the file appears and finishes writing. Of course, a simple change of `2>&1` will fix the problem but the change of behavior seems a bit surprising.

Comment: Maybe use parens for grouping:  `system(" ( foo >> test.log ) & ")` ?  That is of course untested...

Comment: What's really needed is `foo 2>&1 >> test.log` which is equivalent with `foo &>> test.log` in shell, as mentioned, but now R 3.4 suddenly execute this like `foo & >> test.log`, inconsistent with shell commands

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in R but different linux distro may choose different shell for `sh`, as pointed out ["&>>" in sh behaves differently in Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Fedora 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320065/in-sh-behaves-differently-in-ubuntu-16-04-2-and-fedora-24)