# "&>>" in sh behaves differently in Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Fedora 24

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, fedora

Consider the following sh command:

```
sh -c 'sleep 3 &>> /dev/null'
```

`&>>` is supposed to redirect `stdout` and `stderr`. However, it is interpreted differently in Fedora 24 and Ubuntu 16.04.2.

In Fedora 24, it works exactly in this way, and the command above waits until `sleep` ends.

In Ubuntu 16.04.2, the command runs like `sleep 3 & >> /dev/null`, that is, `sleep` is sent to background and the command exits immediately.

The difference causes weired problems and cannot be easily found since I call things like `foo arg1 arg2 output_file &>> test.log` in a R script and expect the command ends with `output_file` is written. In Fedora 24, it works as expected but to my surprise the behavior changes in Ubuntu 16.04.2.

I'm not sure if this is a documented behavior.

Comment: probably `sh` is link to `bash` in Fedora? does `bash -c 'sleep 3 &>> /dev/null'` work on Ubuntu?

Comment: If you are writing the null stream you don't need the append `>>` just `>` would suffice, i.e. `sh -c 'sleep 3 &> /dev/null'
`

Comment: `bash -c 'sleep 3 &>> /dev/null` works exactly the same on both sides

Comment: Yes, I find sh -> bash on Fedora while sh -> dash on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`sh` is not `bash`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Scripts).
- `sh` in Fedora is `bash`, which when invoked as `sh` behaves "closely" to [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html).
- [`sh` in Ubuntu is `dash`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).
- [`&>>` is a bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism#Redirections).

The last link explains how to fix it for `dash` (the `sh` in Ubuntu):

```
sh -c 'sleep 3 > /dev/null 2>&1'
```

This will also work in Bash. Note the single `>` - you don't need to use the append operator (`>>`) with /dev/null.

Tip: Seeing this it might be tempting to write all your scripts to be compatible with both implementations of `sh`, but you'll only make your life unnecessarily difficult. Use the *most* powerful shell which you can expect to be available by default on all the platforms you're interested in. In your case this would be `bash` (version 4), which is also the default on many other distros.